# How to create index type and id in create index request?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

I am using IndexRequest from elastic 6.3.2. Now I changed to version 7.6.2. How can I do the same below steps using the CreateIndexRequest?

Elastic rest high level client 6.3.2 code:

```
 public Object createIndex(Object document, String id) throws IOException {

        Map documentMapper = objectMapper.convertValue(document, Map.class);

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(this.getIndexName(),
                type, id).source(documentMapper, XContentType.JSON);

        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

After switching to 7.6.2 I am not able to create type, id and source in CreateIndexRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

types are deprecated in Elasticsearch 7.X and below is the code, which works for me using the resthighlevel client.

**Please note I am not using the `type` and `id` in `CreateIndexRequest` method of `resthighlevel` client.**

```
String indexString = jsonUtil.getStringFromFile(indexName + ".mapping");
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
request.source(indexString, XContentType.JSON);
client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Please see [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) for more information.